# How to check a datagridview was sorted or not?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sorting, datagridview

Datagridview can reorder rows by user drag datagridrow  move up and down.
They can order either Ascending or Descending order.
Such as A,B,C  or C,B,A  is OK. 
But B,A,C is not OK.

How to if Datagridview isn't sort?

Comment: Asking questions here without first having done your own research isn't really acceptable. If the answer to your question is contained in the MSDN documentation for the specific class you're asking about then you haven't really done your own research.

Answer (score 0):

```
If DataGridView1.SortedColumn Is Nothing Then
    'Isn't sorted
Else
    'It is sorted
End If
```